# Rendering a child route in the parent in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

With Angular 2, I could make a child route render "over" its parent by defining an empty `path` and creating an essentially empty base component.  I am trying to accomplish something similar with the new Angular router (version 4.3.1), but have hit a roadblock.

To reproduce my problem, [here's a Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/BKELPGqyJrOCvEKahoFn?p=preview)  The routes are defined as:

```
[{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/master",
    pathMatch: "full"
}, {
    path: 'master',
    component: MasterComponent,
    children: [{
        path: 'detail/:value',
        component: DetailComponent,
        children: [{
            path: 'subdetail',
            component: SubDetailComponent
        }]
    }]
}]
```

When I navigate to a detail page, the master page is still visible because I have added a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to `MasterComponent`.  What I need is to replace the master view with the detail.  I can accomplish this by making `detail/:value` a *sibling* of `master` rather than a child, but this isn't logically correct in my application and breaks my breadcrumbs.

Is there any proper way to handle this kind of pattern, or will I have to pick a workaround, such as [showing and hiding the intended route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224233/angular-2-children-component-in-parents-router-outlet) or [manually specifying a dedicated "main" outlet for every link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392470/angular-2-sub-apps-parent-child-nested-components-nested-router-outlet-desig)?

The only existing solution that comes close is to [define a dummy parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841976/angular-2-have-child-route-component-replace-parent-in-router-outlet), but this only works one-level down.  If my detail page has another sub-detail page that should also replace master, it gets very messy.

Is there any route-level flag I can set or design pattern to implement to elegantly accomplish this?  I am an Angular 2 beginner, but I feel as though something like this should be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no "new" router in 4.3.1. It's the same router from 2.x.

Second, there were a few changes I needed to make to your plunker to make it work appropriately. The key change was this in the master.component.ts:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail', 5]">
```

I added a slash. Without the slash it was looking for a route named `master/detail/5`

The route definition is now flat, so everything will appear "under" your main header.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'master',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'master',
    component: MasterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:value',
    component: DetailComponent
  }
];
```

The updated plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/EHehUR6qSi248vQPDntt?p=preview

Comment: Hi DeborahK, thank you!  I was hoping I wouldn't have to flatten out my routes, as this breaks breadcrumbs.  Is there no other way to force a route to be rendered at the base level?

Comment: How are you implementing bread crumbs? If you want the new content to completely replace the old content then it cannot be a child route without a bunch of finagling. But you could potentially set the paths to be `master/detail/:value` if the bread crumb implementation is reading the full URL.

Comment: I'm using a modified version of [this technique](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/23/angular2-breadcrumb-using-router/), which just recurses through each active route.  Having operable breadcrumbs is definitely a secondary objective to having the page display correctly though.

Comment: Did you read the first comment in the discussion section? Looks like several other devs are trying to do the same thing. The last person proposed a solution.

Comment: I'll be honest, since comments aren't often a great source of information (except for both of these situations of course), I completely skipped them.  Looks like some people have some great solutions to the problem though; thanks for pointing that out.  I'm not sure who downvoted your answer, but it answers my question and fixes my routes.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Yea, I wish all down votes required entry of a reason ...

Comment: How does it possible to generate breadcrumb out of flat structure ? So far what I know this solution only loads content to parent router-outlet by it cannot help to generate breadcrumb hierarchy ? And I would really not accept as answer. Anyways @Scott have you found the way to generate breadcrumb out of flat router structure ?

Comment: Modified question with breadcrumb navigation when i come across this situation is posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976360/angular-2-4-5-load-child-component-to-main-router-outlet