# Angular 2/4/5 - Load child component to main router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am working with angular 5 currently. I have came across the problem with my router configuration and its presentation of component content accordingly. As below is my router configuration.

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "home" },
    {
      path: "home", component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
      path: "applications", component: ApplicationsComponent,
      children: [{
        path: ":applicationId/privacysettingsforapplications", component: PrivacysettingsforapplicationsComponent,
        children: [
          { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "services" },
          {
            path: "services", component: PrivacysettingsforapplicationservicesComponent
          },
          {
            path: "data", component: PrivacysettingsforapplicationdataComponent
          }]
      }]
    },
    {
      path: "devices", component: DevicesComponent,
    },
  ];
```

We have one main `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in which angular loads all content of its parent component. Here `ApplicationsComponent` has one children `PrivacysettingsforapplicationsComponent` which in turn has two children(`PrivacysettingsforapplicationservicesComponent and PrivacysettingsforapplicationdataComponent` ie: service and data).

I want to check that is there any way to load(`PrivacysettingsforapplicationsComponent`) children on main `<router-outlet>` instead of its immediate parent `<router-outlet>` ie. `ApplicationComponent`'s. One way I have checked is to put child component as peer to parent component but then my breadcrumb module does not identify who is the real parent of that component `PrivacysettingsforapplicationsComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

`path: "applications/:applicationId/privacysettingsforapplications"`

Replace this with following path

`path: ":applicationId/privacysettingsforapplications"`

Comment: Hi Sachin, path you have suggested is right but it requires <router-outlet></router-outlet> in `ApplicationComponent` but I want to load it in most parent component which is `AppComponent`

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the full path instead of just router path.
e.g. provide path line applications/privacysettingsforapplications/services.

You need to provide the correct path as the above is just an example.

With this the service template will load on parent most router outlet.

Hope this help.